# "<PackageA> is in the dependencies but no package named <PackageA> is present in the workspace" - Error when running pnpm install

Tags: package, monorepo, pnpm

I have multiple packages in a monorepo setup with `pnpm` 8.14.1 and [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) 7.3.0. I'm running the command `pnpm install` and getting the error:

`ERR_PNPM_WORKSPACE_PKG_NOT_FOUND  In packages\<PackageB>: "@mynamespace/<PackageA>@workspace:*" is in the dependencies but no package named "@mynamespace/<PackageA>" is present in the workspace`

I have multiple packages in my monorepo and they're all working fine. I have just added the `<PackageA>` and for some reason my `<PackageB>` is not recognizing it.

Does anyone have an idea what the reason could be?

Comment: not sure if that's really the case or just the error message, but you seem to have an extra `@` in the dependency, `@workspace:*` should be `workspace:*`

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. The error turned out to be that I had forgotten to add the "@mynamespace" to the name of the the new `<PackageA>`. I'll post an answer about it soon.

Comment: also since you use pnpm and if you're not using Nx, I would suggest you take a look at [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) which is more lightweight especially when you don't need Nx because the new Lerna is now depending on Nx behind the scene and Lerna-Lite is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out the be due to a missing namespace in the package name in the package.json file.

Here is what I had:

```json
  ...
  "name": "PackageA",
  ...
```

And here is what it should have been:

```json
  ...
  "name": "@mynamespace/PackageA",
  ...
```